# ORA-00903: invalid table name on PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a method that will execute a query with a list of QueryParameters for the prepared statement. The `HelperConnection` and `QueryParameter` are just small java beans and should be self-explanatory based on the `get`s you see here. I'm try to do a `select * from dual` using, instead a `select * from ?` where the `QueryParameter` is a STRING type and the value is `dual`. However, I'm getting a `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00903: invalid table name` error. My code and output are below. What's up?

```
public static ResultSet executeQuery(HelperConnection helperConnection, String query, QueryParameter... params) throws SQLException {
  System.out.println("The connection is: " + helperConnection.getJdbcURL());
  System.out.println("The query is: " + query);
  if (params.length > 0) {
    System.out.println("The QueryParameters are:");
    System.out.println("\t" + StringHelper.splitBy(StringHelper.newline + "\t", params));
  }
  Connection conn = helperConnection.createOracleConnection();
  PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  for (int i = 1; i <= params.length; i++) {
    QueryParameter param = params[i - 1];
    switch (param.getType()) {
      //Other cases here
      case QueryParameter.STRING:
        pstmt.setString(i, param.getValue());
        break;
    }
  }

  ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
  conn.commit();
  return rs;
}
```

Output:

```
The connection is: //.....My connection
The query is: select * from ?
The QueryParameters are:
    String - dual
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that `PreparedStatement` parameters are only for *values* - not for parts of the SQL query such as tables. There may be some databases which support what you're trying to achieve, but I don't believe Oracle is one of them. You'll need to include the table name directly - and cautiously, of course.

Comment: That would make sense! Thanks :)