# Efficient Way to insert into multiple tables at once with same columns and data types

Tags: java, sql, database, prepared-statement

I need to insert into three tables at once for now. But in the future I will be inserting in more than three tables.

All the three tables have same columns and same data types. So I can insert the same data into three tables as well. Currently I am inserting into one table.

I am working with new database named XpressMP. And it supports all the major SQL syntax.

```
public final static String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO COPY"
        + "("
        + "ID, ACCOUNT) VALUES"
        + "(?, ?)";

preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);

preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
preparedStatement.setString(2, ACCOUNT);
```

What will be the best way to insert into three tables at once? It is possible to do in a SQL? Or I need to make a change in the Java code to insert into multiple tables?

Comment: "_All the three tables have same columns and same data types._" Why isn't one table then?

Comment: Can the table name be a parameter ? I think that is supported - did you test that? - Although that is not all at once, atleast you have the same code.

Comment: No table names can't be Prepared Statement parameter in most DBMSes

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841952/ora-00903-invalid-table-name-on-preparedstatement

Comment: Are there located in one database, or multiple databases? I believe they are in different database instances, and your need is replication, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parameterize the [table name part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841952/ora-00903-invalid-table-name-on-preparedstatement). You can create String with tablename and ?, then use that string for preparedStatement.

```
String tablename="COPY";
public final static String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO " + tablename 
        + "("
        + "ID, ACCOUNT) VALUES"
        + "(?, ?)";

preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);

preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
preparedStatement.setString(2, ACCOUNT);
```